# Error "This certificate cannot be verified up to a trusted certification authority"

Tags: ssl-certificate

In my VirtualBox I have following network for testing and every software on virtual machines is a fresh installation.

[image]

On virtual machine, named `www.home.local`, where my web server resides, I **created a certificate request**, then submitted **this request** to `ws01.home.local`, then got a certificate issued and downloaded, then **completed the certificate request**. After that I added binding to **Default Web Site** with `https` protocol and the certificate.

Now,

this **Default Web Site** is accessible from `www.home.local` at `https:www.home.local` without any error

this **Default Web Site** is accessible from `ws01.home.local` at `https:www.home.local` without any error

However, I am getting error from `vm02` and the host computer

[image]

**What can be a solution to this issue? What should I do next?**

Answer (score 1):

The CA (where the certifcate was issued - `home-WS01-CA`) is not trusted by your client. You should export the CA root certificate **without the key** and then import it to your client. Also export/import should be done for intermediate authority, if any. I don't think you have an intermediate authority, just mentioning for future production ready systems.

You should also add the root CA cert to the web server also. So that on all involved machines the whole chain of certificates is trusted.

---

Adding info: Have a look at this link: [exporting/importing ssl certs, Win/IIS](https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/certificate-pfx-file-export-import-iis-10.htm)

You'll start from `home-WS01-CA`.
In 7th step, you'll look for `Trusted Root Certification authorities`. There should be the Root CA cert. as shown in the link, you'll export it to a file, but without the key (you won't have such an option for root CA if I recall well, nevertheless if you do, **do not export** the private key). Follow the procedure, probably only .cer file will be available for export (due to no key) and no password.

Continue to import, I suggest to web server first, make a try and then to the client if you still have the problem. Proceed as advised, but choose `Trusted Root Certification authorities` for the import destination instead of `web hosting` mentioned on the link.

---

On the screenshot you attached, 3rd tab `certification path`, when everything is correct you should see something like this: [cert path, root, intermediate, cert](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-847kblIeEUc/U0_Axd5xHEI/AAAAAAAAI_I/0o-ZVcdttVI/s1600/certificate+properties1.jpg). Without the intermediate apparently.

Comment: Kindly, can you please give how-to-do steps in details? I am learning all of this stuff, so not very knowledgeable in general instructions. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: On `ws01.home.local`, I found a certificate called `home-WS01-CA` in Trusted Root Certificates folder, exported it, then imported into client webbrowser. I am not getting error this time but the browser (Chrome) is still giving a Privacy error with a warning about attackers. Any idea?

Comment: It says "Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.home.local (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards)." NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Comment: You shouldn't import it to browser, but to web server's and probably client's trusted root certificates. Look through the additions in my answer.

Comment: I can't understand why you are suggesting to start from `home-WS01-CA`, export from there and import into IIS's machine. Doesn't this get automatically installed on IIS's machine when certificate request is completed?

Comment: Because on IIS's machine the certificate for trusted authority is already present